# Android TextView URL

Tags: android, url, onclick, textview, onclicklistener

In android, a TextView with a URL can be clicked to open the URL in the web by using:

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

What I would like to do is instead capture this click and if this TextView contains a URL, then I would like to display a Dialog. How can I go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your text is url or not.

```
try {
    new URI(YourText);
    // show your dialog here
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // Certainly not an URL
}
```

Comment: Okay, I will try it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply, by implement setOnCclikListener, check your string of TextView if it's a URL display the dialog.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class URLValidator {

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    private static final String URL_PATTERN = 
        "/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/";

    public URLValidator() {
        pattern = Pattern.compile(URL_PATTERN);
    }

    //Validate your input string 
    public boolean validate(final String url) {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

Check your text get from TextView

```
URLValidator validator = new URLValidator();
if(validator.valiadte("yourString")) {
    //Show your dialog
}
```

Comment: How can I check if its a URL

Comment: @26hmkk `String url = textView.getText().toString();
                if (url.isEmpty() || !Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()) {
                    // invalid Url;
                } else {
 // valid Url
 }`

Comment: Can you make this an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Check my answer again!